# Django inlineformset_factory. Request.FILES not returning filename to form when formset.is_valid() = False

Tags: django

I'm trying to allow the user to upload images tied to a project. I'm doing this via an inlineformset_factory.

Im serving the form to the user trough a function based view. When the user fails to fill in one (or more) of the formsets correctly formset.is_valid() returns false and the bound formsets get returned to the user along with error messages. What i'm having trouble with is that the imagefield is not returned to the bound form. So if the user has filled in 2 out of 3 forms correctly then neither of the formsets have a bound imagefield after the failed validation. I can't manage to figure out if this is working as intended or if i'm doing something wrong. If i print out request.FILES i get the following:

```
<MultiValueDict: {'image_set-0-filename': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: IMG_0017.jpg (image/jpeg)>], 'image_set-1-filename': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: sprite.svg (image/svg+xml)>]}>
```

I would like the imagefield to be bound and show the user what value the field has.

[before incorrect form submission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuWMG.png)

[after incorrect form submission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smh4t.png)

Hopefully you can see where my mistake is or tell me if i'm thinking about this the wrong way.

Thank you in advance

forms.py

```
class EndUserImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ["filename", "description"]
        widgets = {
        "filename": forms.FileInput(attrs={"class": "form__field no--outline"}),
        "description": forms.Textarea(attrs={"class": "form__field no--outline", "placeholder":    "Description"})
        }

EndUserImageInlineFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Project, Image, form=EndUserImageForm, extra=2)
```

views.py

```
def image_formset(request, pk):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=pk)

    image_formset = EndUserImageInlineFormset(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    context = {
        "image_formset": image_formset
        }

    if request.method == "POST":
        if image_formset.is_valid():
            images = image_formset.save(commit=False)
            for image in images:
                image.project = project
                image.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("projects:home"))
    return render(request, "projects/test.html", context)
```

template

```
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h4>Add Images</h4>
        {{ image_formset.non_form_errors }}
        {{ image_formset.management_form }}
        <div id="image-form-list">    
        
        {% for form in image_formset %}
             {{ form.errors }}    
             <div class="image_form">
                {{ form.filename }} 
                {{ form.description }} 
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="button button--main activate"/>
    </form>
```

models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    filename = models.ImageField(upload_to=project_directory_path, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=350, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def image_formset(request, pk):
     project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=pk)
     image_formset = EndUserImageInlineFormset()
```

if request.method == "POST":
image_formset = EndUserImageInlineFormset(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

if image_formset.is_valid():h
images = image_formset.save(commit=False)
for image in images:
image.project = project
image.save()

Comment: Does your input field accept multiple file (more than one image???). If your accepting multipe image once change user getlist() method on receiving data

Comment: Hi @Cybergates, 

No, each input field only accepts one image. I can't seem to get your suggested solution to work the way I wan't it to work. I get the same result when I move image_formset = EndUserImageInlineFormset(request.POST, request.FILES) inside of request.method == "POST". All the image-values I inputed are wiped from the forms when one form doesn't pass validation